# jQuery ajax - call various MVC controller actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller (`RequestsController`) with several actions (all taking one parameter)

For example:

- `public List<Models.AcceptRequests> GetAllAcceptRequests(int passedId)`
- `public List<Models.Requests> GetAllRequests(int passedId)`
- `public List<Models.CancelRequests> GetAllCancelRequests(int passedId)`

I am calling each of these actions from `jQuery` `ajax` as follows:

> ```
>         var s =
>         {
>             passedId: 0,
>         }
>         $.ajax({
>             url: "../api/Requests/GetAllAcceptRequests",
>             type: "GET",
>             dataType: 'json',
>             data: JSON.stringify(s),
>             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>             success: function (response) {
>                 vm.Requests(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS(response)));
>             }
>         });
> ```

I receive the following error:

`Multiple actions were found that match the request: System.Collections.Generic.List1 [TCMSWeb.Models.Requests] GetAllRequests(Int32)`

It is my understanding that you can call a `controller` `action` regardless of the parameters conflicting with other actions.
Is this not the case then?

How can I call each `controller` `action` without having to specify a unique number of parameters for each?

**EDIT:**

> ```
>     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
>     {
>         routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
> ```

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the routing config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Register method in WebApiConfig.cs like this.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

This will enable RPC style routing. Also, change your jQuery call, like this. 1234 is just hard-coded data which will be bound to passedId parameter.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../api/Requests/GetAllAcceptRequests?passedid=1234",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            vm.Requests(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS(response)));
        }
    });
```

You can also use `url: "../api/Requests/GetAllAcceptRequests/1234"`, if you change the route mapping to

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{passedid}",
    defaults: new { passedid = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is my understanding that you can call a controller action regardless of the parameters conflicting with other actions

No, this understanding is wrong. This only makes the C# compiler happy but is invalid in ASP.NET MVC. You cannot have 2 controller actions with the same name on the same controller accessible **with the same HTTP verb** regardless of the parameters they are taking.

Comment: They don't have the same name.

Comment: @Stijn, how do you know that?

Comment: Because it's at the top of his question? Unless the real actions all have the same name and his examples are just that: examples.

Comment: Precisely, that was my point. His real actions are probably different.

Comment: My actions all have different names but the same parameter.

Comment: Did you include the action name in your route definition: `{controller}/{action}/{id}`? Because by default when you create a new ASP.NET Web API project the route definition looks like this: `{controller}/{id}` which doesn't allow you to specify an action name at all, which is a good thing by the way because in a RESTful service this is something that the HTTP verb should decide. So basically your Web API controller should not have such action names. It should have the standard HTTP verbs as action names: Get, Post, Put, Delete.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov
So the `action` portion of the route is simply when you have an action that does not use HTTP verbs? For example `DetermineTime`.

Using actions in the route won't then allow me to access methods in the controller with the same parameters?